# Expand editor control does not work on iPad

Tags: bug, editor

The expand editor control does not work on iPad.
Can it be made to work on iPad?

[image: screen shot showing control]

Comment: Also does not work on Android on SE sites, even though other sites that have the grabber do work (but sometimes it's tricky to grab). Being able to expand a bit would greatly improve composition on mobile devices. I often have to scroll down to the bottom of the preview to double check that everything is OK - fortunately double-double-tap scrolls you back to the edit window.